# Angularjs ng-disabled not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

I'm trying to enable a button only when my input is filled with at least 18 characters. Here is the HTML code:

```
<form id="frm.frmEntidade" name="frm.frmEntidade">
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="entidade.cnpj" id="cnpjEntidade" name="cnpjEntidade" required />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button title="Buscar Entidade" class="btn btn-primary" 
              type="button" ng-click="buscarEntidade(entidade.cnpj)" ng-
              disabled="frm.frmEntidade.cnpjEntidade.lenght !== 18">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

but the button stay awas disabled, anyone could help?

Comment: Try `ng-disabled="entidade.cnpj.lenght !== 18"`

Comment: just advice, you say `"with at least 18 characters..."`, then you should be using `>=18`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo  error on the word `length`. Change:

```
<button [...]
        ng-disabled="frm.frmEntidade.cnpjEntidade.lenght !== 18">
```

To:

```
<button [...]
        ng-disabled="frm.frmEntidade.cnpjEntidade.length !== 18">
```

*As a side note, this condition check if it is **different** from 18, not if "input is filled with at least 18 characters".*

Comment: i did not make myself clear, it's a document with a mask "00.000.000/0000-00" and i want to enable the button if the user types exactly in this way

Answer (score 0):

try `ng-disabled="entidade.cnpj.length!=18"`

Answer (score 0):

It's better use `ng-minlength` for form validation. by checking `$valid` you can enable or disable button

```
<form id="frm.frmEntidade" name="frm.frmEntidade">
<input type="text" ng-model="entidade.cnpj" id="cnpjEntidade" name="cnpjEntidade" required ng-minlength="18" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button title="Buscar Entidade" class="btn btn-primary" 
          type="button" ng-click="buscarEntidade(entidade.cnpj)" 
          ng-disabled="!frm.frmEntidade.$valid">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
             Button
              </button>
   </span>  
</form>
```